# Free Blog site that allows PHP?

Tags: php, blog, free, post

I was wondering if anyone knows of a free blog site (ie wordpress, blogspot, livejournal) that allows people to include php into their posts?

Any leads would be greatly appreciate.

cheers!

Comment: Question needs clarification - are you looking for [PHP hosting](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) or the ability to publish code snippets?

Answer (score 4):

You're unlikely to find a free hosted blog platform that allows PHP; it would be hard to block access to functions that could prove harmful to other users of the service without crippling PHP severely.

If you want more control than a hosted blogging platform like [WordPress.com](http://wordpress.com) offers, try downloading a copy of WordPress yourself from [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org), then [setting it up](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress) on a cheap shared server with one of the [hosting partners](http://wordpress.org/hosting/) they recommend.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There's a pretty significant problem here in that regardless of the hosting service, most CMS applications by default won't let you put arbitrary code into the *content* anyway. It'll usually just get stripped on output.

There are often ways to force it(eg. Wordpress' [Exec-PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/)), but it's highly unlikely any hosted service is going to offer you that, for basically the reasons in Nick's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean runnable PHP? If so then no, I don't think their are any, and if they did I would not be recommending them.

If you mean so you can do something like;

```
$x = 5;
echo $x
```

Then most will come with at the very least code for using the `<pre>` tag and if not Wordpress has several plugins that will do this and will work on the free install.